# How To make Table Views in JavaFx Responsive?

Tags: java, javafx, responsive-design, fxml

I have been trying to make a simple UI, where there is a MenuBar in Top section and 4 Table Views in the Center Section of the BorderLayout. What i want is that these 4 tables should show like a 2by2 Matrix. I mean 2 rows and 2 columns and then these tables should grow and shrink according to the screen size or as i resize the frame.

The table views and growing and shrinking in height well. But i am not able to adjust the width. What i want is, I want a responsive design for the tables. Tables height and width should grow and shrink as i resize the frame. The height part is working fine but i am unable to implement this functionality for width.

Here is my FXML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ui_designs.HelloController">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bills">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Walk In Bill" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder Bill" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Product" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Purchase Request" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock Arrival" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stcok Exchange" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account Holder" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder's Transactions" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Accounts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Transactions" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Daily Report" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <HBox spacing="10.0">
                <!-- First VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox spacing="10.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Table 1 Heading" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>

                <!-- Second VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox spacing="10.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Table 2 Heading" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </HBox>
         <HBox spacing="10.0">
            <children>
               <VBox spacing="10.0">
                  <children>
                     <Label text="Table 1 Heading" />
                     <TableView>
                        <columns>
                           <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                           <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                        </columns>
                     </TableView>
                  </children>
               </VBox>
               <VBox spacing="10.0">
                  <children>
                     <Label text="Table 2 Heading" />
                     <TableView>
                        <columns>
                           <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                           <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                        </columns>
                     </TableView>
                  </children>
               </VBox>
            </children>
         </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Merely resizing (growing/shrinking) is not [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: If you want the *columns* of the TableView to be resized when the TableView is resized then you probably want to ensure you are using an appropriate [column resize policy](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#columnResizePolicyProperty) (in addition to the other recommendations noted for resizing the entire table in the various answers you have received).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`fillWidth="true"`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty) to all the `VBox` instances, and [`HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.scene.layout.Priority)) to the four "inner" `VBox` instances:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bills">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Walk In Bill" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder Bill" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Product" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Purchase Request" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock Arrival" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stcok Exchange" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account Holder" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder's Transactions" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Accounts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Transactions" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Daily Report" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="true">
            <HBox spacing="10.0">
                <!-- First VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox spacing="10.0" fillWidth="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Table 1 Heading" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>

                <!-- Second VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox spacing="10.0" fillWidth="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Table 2 Heading" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </HBox>
            <HBox spacing="10.0">
                <children>
                    <VBox spacing="10.0" fillWidth="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <children>
                            <Label text="Table 1 Heading" />
                            <TableView>
                                <columns>
                                    <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                    <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                                </columns>
                            </TableView>
                        </children>
                    </VBox>
                    <VBox spacing="10.0" fillWidth="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <children>
                            <Label text="Table 2 Heading" />
                            <TableView>
                                <columns>
                                    <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                    <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                                </columns>
                            </TableView>
                        </children>
                    </VBox>
                </children>
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Often a `GridPane` is easier than nesting `HBox` and `VBox` instances:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bills">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Walk In Bill" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder Bill" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Product" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Purchase Request" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock Arrival" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stcok Exchange" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account Holder" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder's Transactions" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Accounts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Transactions" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Daily Report" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="10"  BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="true" hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
                <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="true" hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints/>
                <RowConstraints fillHeight="true" vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
                <RowConstraints/>
                <RowConstraints fillHeight="true" vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Table 1 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
                <Label text="Table 2 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
                <Label text="Table 1 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
                <Label text="Table 2 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added borders and colors so that you can see what's happening better.

I used a GridPane and allowed the GridPane and its children to fill all available space using `MAX_VALUE` on their `Max Height` property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ui_designs.HelloController">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bills">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Walk In Bill" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder Bill" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Product" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Purchase Request" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock Arrival" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stcok Exchange" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account Holder" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder's Transactions" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Accounts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Transactions" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Daily Report" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
   <center>
      <GridPane hgap="7.0" vgap="7.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
                <!-- First VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: black;" text="Table 1 Heading" textFill="WHITE" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>

                <!-- Second VBox with TableView -->
                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: black;" text="Table 2 Heading" textFill="WHITE" />
                        <TableView>
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                                <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: black;" text="Table 4 Heading" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <TableView>
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 3;" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: black;" text="Table 3 Heading" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <TableView>
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As there can be many ways to address an issue, below is my version :)
This uses the GridPane (same as in @SedJ601 answer), but I eliminated all the extra VBox wrappers. Normally I prefer to keep the node count as low as possible.

You can consider the percentWidth property of ColumnConstraints to adjust the layout equally.

For alignment of Labels you can set the GridPane alignment properties on Label (as in below code).

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bills">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Walk In Bill" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder Bill" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Product" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Purchase Request" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock Arrival" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stcok Exchange" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account Holder" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Account Holder's Transactions" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Accounts" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Company Transactions" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reports">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Daily Report" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="10"/>
            </padding>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50"/>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Table 1 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>

                <Label text="Table 2 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="1"  GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>

                <Label text="Table 3 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="0"  GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>

                <Label text="Table 4 Heading" GridPane.columnIndex="1"  GridPane.rowIndex="2"  GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER"/>
                <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn text="Column 1" />
                        <TableColumn text="Column 2" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```